# Board game that you set up each time differently with little cards

Tags: identify-this-game

I played it in probably early 90s. You had little cards and each time you played you put down the cards or tiles along the spaces on the board so each time you played it was different. They were like go back 3 spaces or go forward 2 spaces. I remember I had played it so much I knew the best way to set the board up. It was essentially a make it yourself game. This is driving me crazy! I thought it was similar to grape escape or splat BC I thought maybe it came with playdough but I'm not sure if I'm just remembering wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Can you remember any more clues? What was the shape of the cards/tiles? What did the player pieces look like? Was it a flat board or did it have 3D elements like Grape Escape (and many other play-dough games).

Comment: One of [these](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/7373/play-doughclay-games#linkeditems) (There are 7 pages...)

Answer (score 5):

The description of playing cards on a track that have different movement instructions sounds like "This Game Is Bonkers".  I had this in late 80s early 90s so it would fit the time frame.

It was a roll and move game.  When you landed on an empty space you would play a tile from your hand with an instruction such as 'back 3' or 'forward 2' with the objective of trying to land on scoring spaces.

Only thing that doesn't fit is play dough as thats not in this game but you did say you might have remembered that wrong.

[BGG link to game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1943/game-bonkers)